# Rebuild StreamBuilder when sharedPreference changes

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I'm using a StreamBuilder to dynamically build a ListView which gets a stream of data from a database. Now, I also want to have some settings for the app saved as shared preferences. When the user changes one of these settings, the StreamBuilder (and thus the List) should rebuild.

I tried wrapping it in a FutureBuilder, but this doesn't seem right.

Here is my StreamBuilder widget:

```dart
class Overview extends StatelessWidget {
  Overview({super.key});

  Future<int> getDate() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getInt('startDate') ?? 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getDate(),
      builder: (context, future) {
        return Container(
          height: 230,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [
                  Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                  Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
                ]),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                  spreadRadius: 2,
                  blurRadius: 8,
                  offset: Offset(0, 2))
            ],
          ),
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: database.watchAll(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              ...
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [streaming_share_prefernces](https://pub.dev/packages/streaming_shared_preferences) library that allows you watch for changes inside your preferences